# process.standardoutput.ReadToEnd() always empty?

Tags: c#, process

I'm starting a console application, but when I redirect the standard output I always get nothing!

When I don't redirect it, and set `CreateNoWindow` to `false`, I see everything correctly in the console, but when I redirect it, `StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` always returns an empty string.

```
        Process cproc = new Process();
        cproc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cproc.StartInfo.FileName = Dest;
        cproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cproc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        cproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cproc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        cproc.Start();
        cproc.Exited += new EventHandler(cproc_Exited);
        while(!stop)
        {
           result += cproc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

The `EventHandler cproc_exited` just sets `stop` to `true`. Can someone explain why `result` is always `string.Empty`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why are you looping? Once it's read to the end, it's not going to be able to read any more data, is it?

Are you sure the text is actually being written to `StandardOutput` rather than `StandardError`?

(And yes, obviously you want to set `RedirectStandardOutput` to true rather than false. I assumed that was just a case of you copying the wrong version of your code.)

EDIT: As I've advised in the comments, you should read from standard output and standard error in separate threads. Do *not* wait until the process has exited - this can end up with a deadlock, where you're waiting for the process to exit, but the process is blocking trying to write to stderr/stdout because you haven't read from the buffer.

Alternatively you can subscribe to the OutputDataReceived and ErrorDataReceived events, to avoid using extra threads.

Comment: if I change it to  
while (!stop)
            {
               
            }
            s += convproc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
i get a deadlock

Comment: heey, it works!! looks like my friend (who made the console programm) messed it up! it writes everything in the error stream!! I'll have to talk to him, maybe he can fix this. Thanks for youre quick answer! you saved me from sitting hours and hours in front of my pc and trying to search for a stupid error :)

Comment: @alex: Take out that while loop - it shouldn't be there. Ideally, use separate threads - one to read from `StandardOutput` and one to read from `StandardError`.

Comment: well I now changed it from `ReadToEnd` to `ReadLine`

Comment: @alex: In that case you *will* need a loop (until ReadLine returns false) - but unless you actually need the data before the process finishes, I would strongly encourage you to use ReadToEnd from two threads (one for stdout, one for stderr).

Comment: @alex: It's empty right now, but do you really want to end up with a deadlock if that changes in the future?

Comment: I had about 20 deadlocks today, I do not need any more of them. Well youre right, I'll loose nothing if I just read from stdout. That'll save me time in future

Answer (score 20):

Best way for this is to redirect the output and wait for the events:

```
    // not sure if all this flags are needed
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += process_ErrorDataReceived;
    process.Exited += process_Exited;
    process.Start();

    void process_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something when process terminates;
    }

    void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // a line is writen to the out stream. you can use it like:
        string s = e.Data;
    }

    void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // a line is writen to the out stream. you can use it like:
        string s = e.Data;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You have redirection of standard out disabled. Try changing

```
cproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
```

into

```
cproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

Does the following sample from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) work for you?

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
p.Start();
// Do not wait for the child process to exit before
// reading to the end of its redirected stream.
// p.WaitForExit();
// Read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: well this makes the window appear-but thats empty, and my result string is empty, too.
this is really confusing

Comment: Have you checked standard error: `output = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();`?

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the loop and move the call to `ReadToEnd` to `cproc_Exited`.

Comment: Bad idea: the process will hang if it tries to write a lot of data which nothing is reading.