# C# Process not receiving inputs

Tags: c#, process

I have a process that calls a fortran executable. The executable requests a file from the user and performs operations to find a solution. If multiple solutions are found on the file, the program will ask the user if they would like to find the most optimal solution, basically 2 inputs for the program. The executable then generates a text file that provide results of the program.

The process is able to run, however the resulting text file is not generated. Also when I checked for the output of the application, the message prompt ("Enter a file") is the only thing stored in the string and it doesn't include the secondary prompt for the optimal solution ("Would you like to find the most optimal solution?"). Can anyone give me an idea as to why this is happening? Thanks.

```
Process exeProcess = new Process();
exeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "sdf45.exe";
exeProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
exeProcess.Start();        
//input file                
exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(filePath));            
//find optimal solution
exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y");
string output = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();            
exeProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: How does executable requests a file from the user?

Comment: So I see you're redirecting standard error without reading it.  That could cause problems if the program writes a lot to standard error.

Comment: The executable asks for the name of the file, which is in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Is it possible that your C# commands execute too fast? I mean, the fortran program can't keep up with your inputs. I will try to insert some Thread.Sleep or Application.DoEvents.

Comment: There are plenty of failure modes here.  First one is that a fortran program has never heard of UAC.  So the file could actually be written but ended up in isolated storage.  The weirdo prompting behavior is standard too, a redirected program doesn't flush its output until the program writes a new-line.

Comment: @Steve All of that is bufferered for you by the OS.  You can write to  processes input stream before it even requests for information; your data goes into a buffer, and then when the program does need something it pulls from that buffer (and waits if the buffer doesn't have what it needs).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this line is executing (and returning) before the FORTRAN process even has a chance to read the input:

```
string output = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I am not 100% sure what the result of `ReadToEnd();` on an unbounded stream is in this case.  The proper way to do this, as mentioned by Jon Skeet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012509/process-standardoutput-readtoend-always-empty), is to read from stdout in another thread or better yet asynchronously, as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx

For posterity's sake a rough example:

```
var outputReader = new Thread(ReadOutput);
outputReader.Start(exeProcess);
```

where ReadOutput is defined something like this:

```
public void ReadOutput(Object processState) {
    var process = processState as Process;
    if (process == null) return;
    var output = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    // Do whetever with output
}
```

Making your initial method:

```
Process exeProcess = new Process();
exeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "sdf45.exe";
exeProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
exeProcess.Start();        
//input file                
exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(filePath));            
//find optimal solution
exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y");
var outputReader = new Thread(ReadOutput);
outputReader.Start(exeProcess);
exeProcess.WaitForExit();
outputReader.Join();
```

Comment: While reading from standard out isn't at all a bad idea, I find it unlikely that it is the OPs problem.  ReadToEnd is blocking, so it won't return until the program sends it's end of stream message, which the program won't send until it's ready to exit (unless some mean/incompetent programmer writes the EOS token to standard out when there is still more content to write out).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say, but I **presume** that you need to pass an arguments to the executable, like this

```
Process exeProcess = new Process();
exeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "sdf45.exe";
exeProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
exeProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Path.GetFileName(filePath); //pass file path to EXE
exeProcess.Start();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: From the OP, it seems like the file name is passed via stdin (after a prompt), not parameters.

Comment: @ChrisShain: not very clear actually *that* point. Would be nice if Op's clarifies it.