# Redirect standard output of exe to my Console application

Tags: c#, console-application, redirectstandardoutput

There is an executable called jlink.exe that I will like to make of use on my console application. Because jlink.exe is not a .net application it is not possible for me to reference it and call it's methods. **As a result I will like to use it reading it's output**

When I start that exe from windows explorer this is how it looks:
[image]

It then waits for a command. If I type `mem 88 2` then I get back:

[image]

Now I will like to do the same thing with my .net console application reading it's standard output but for some reason I cannot read the output. This is what I have:

```
    // change working directory
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.4 Evaluation\arm\bin");

    Process p = new Process( )
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( @"jlink.exe" )
        {
            UseShellExecute = false ,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true ,
            RedirectStandardInput = true
        }
    };

    p.Start( );                       

    StreamWriter standardInput = p.StandardInput;
    StreamReader standardOutput = p.StandardOutput;

    var line = string.Empty;

    while ( ( line = standardOutput.ReadLine( ) ) != null )
    {                
        Console.WriteLine( line );                
    }
```

why when I run that code I just get a black window... I do not get the same output as when running that executable. When I run that code against other executable it works great.

If I then type `mem 88 2` and press ENTER nothing happens. If I press enter one more time then I finally get what I want with extra content. Why am I getting this behavior with that executable?

### Edit

I have looked at similar question such as this one:

[process.standardoutput.ReadToEnd() always empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012509/process-standardoutput-readtoend-always-empty)

I don't think I am doing something wrong. I guess there is something weird with that executable. To use that executable you may download it at:  http://supp.iar.com/Download/SW/?item=EWARM-EVAL or at http://www.iar.com/en/Products/IAR-Embedded-Workbench/ARM/ . Then go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.4 Evaluation\arm\bin` and execute jlink.exe (If you do not have a board connected via usb you will get an error but it does not matter. the error message does not show up either).

Comment: Is it possible that it's not sending a line terminator until you type something else?

Comment: I doubt it is not sending the line terminator because if you run that same code against a different executable it will work... Even if I do `standardInput.Write("Foo" + "\r\n\r\n") I will still have to manually press enter for the input to be send to the exe.

Comment: Did you check if it's sending the output to stdout and not to sterr.

Comment: yeah nothing is being send to standardError's stream...